# Ubuntu 21: Top bar for all monitors

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, gnome-shell-extension

Since the update to the new Ubuntu 21 (particulary, in this moment, I'm on Ubuntu 21.10), due to the GNOME newer version 40+, I was no more able to use [multi-monitor-add-on](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/), so that I cannot have the top bar on all the connected monitors.

Are there any alternatives? Any workaround I can do myself?

I just need the top bar to be on all monitors.

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu 21.10, please edit your question to be specific about this.

Comment: Ubuntu has products that use the *year* format, but these only occur on *even* years so there is no release of such products in 2021, and products that use the *year.month* format (eg. Ubuntu 21.10 meaning the 2021-October release).  You mention GNOME which implies a *desktop* system, but they are only available in the *year.month* releases such as Ubuntu 21.10.  Please be precise & accurate with details, and don't make them up. Are you using Ubuntu? if so please give details.

Comment: check here: https://github.com/realh/multi-monitors-add-on . You can click on the `Code` green button, then `Download zip`, then copy the folder `multi-monitors-add-on@spin83` in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

Comment: @LorenzKeel this does not work for me, when I move the folder to extensions, then in extension app I have a red X ver the aforementioned extension.